# What are LaTeX templates for A5 booklets?

Tags: paper-size, booklet

I am trying to produce a A5 size booklet. You might have seen these old small A5 size math books, with large size text in every page. They are very comfortable on the eyes to read and handy to hold.

I am using documentclass `book`. If I use `a5paper`, the produced PDF is still A4 size with the text being produced in top-left corner of A5 size. Also, the text is pretty small compared to the large font seen in booklets.

Are there LaTeX templates or packages I can use to easily produce this kind of A5 booklet? LaTeX newbie here :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I usually use the `geometry` package, with `a5paper` option (and like `7pt` font size). The use of `a5` size is an excellent idea!

Comment: How to specify font size in geometry?

Comment: I use amsart and specify the font size with that, I think the effect it creates is nice as amsart is a very compact document class and fits well with the smaller paper size.

Comment: but anyway, something like \documentclass[10pt]{book} works (although the range of font sizes is very very limited, although^2 there might be some latex packages for that)

Answer (score 5):

You could consider looking at the source of the [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/lshort-english/lshort.pdf), which you can either find on your machine

```
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/doc/latex/lshort-english
```

(or whichever language is appropriate)

Or else you can unzip `lshort-5.01.src.tar.gz` from http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/ and you'll find `lshort-a5.tex` which you can use as a starting point.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [external: A5 Reports with LaTeX](http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=2224) and [external: Formatting documents for the iPad](http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=2110), maybe you can pull something from these examples.

Answer (score 3):

I usually print two A5-size pages, rotated and side-by-side on a landscape A4 page (four A5 pages per A4 sheet).  For that, I generate a **normal A4 pdf** (perhaps with `12pt` or `\large` text) and then process it with [pdfbook2](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/support/pdfbook2/pdfbook2) (which uses [pdfjam](http://freshmeat.sourceforge.net/projects/pdfjam/) and comes with [TeX Live](https://tug.org/texlive/)).  The result is that the pages are also **ordered** in the correct way, *e.g.* for four pages in the original pdf, pages 1 and 4 end up on the first page of the output pdf, and pages 2 and 3 on the next page, correctly flipped on the long page edge.  As a result, I can fold the A4 sheet in the middle to produce a four-page 'booklet'.  This also works for pdf files containing more pages, in which case I can staple the booklet in the fold.

The graphical Python program [pdfbooklet](http://pdfbooklet.sourceforge.net/) does something similar (though I didn't try it, as I prefer the terminal).